# How to auto import pinia stores in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

Currently I am doing something like this to import stores in components

```
import { useSomeStore } from "~/store/someStore";
const store = useSomeStore();
```

What I would like to achieve is skip the import and just use the store

What I have done is add

```
// nuxt.config.ts
modules: [
  [
    "@pinia/nuxt",
    {
      autoImports: ["defineStore", "acceptHMRUpdate"],
    },
  ],
],
imports: {
  dirs: ["stores"],
},
```

in my nuxt config but I'm still getting useSomeStore is undefined, what am I doing wrong in this case?

The store:

```
// store/someStore.ts
export const useSomeStore = defineStore("some-store", {
  state: () => ({ hello: "there" }),
});
```

Comment: Having `useSomeStore` `undefined` is not the same as not having `defineStore` imported. You would have a `TypeError defineStore is not a function` at runtime if it was the case. Also, does the Typescript compiler complains about `defineStore` or not?

Comment: it doesn't but eslint does, do you know whats the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like a typo to me.  Your component import references location `/store`

```
import { useSomeStore } from "~/store/someStore";
```

but your config references `/stores`

```
imports: {
  dirs: ['stores']
}
```

so is your store folder called `/store` or `/stores`?

Assuming the former, your nuxt config should be:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    [
      "@pinia/nuxt",
      {
        autoImports: ["defineStore", "acceptHMRUpdate"],
      },
    ],
  ],
  imports: {
    dirs: ['store']
  }
});
```

Comment: Some clarification here. It's best practice to put Pinia stores in the folder storeS, vuex stores where put in the folder store without S..